# Get the maximum count for each repeating value in a table and link it to another value

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Please help me figure out this:

Let us say we have a restaurant with 3 different menu items

```
A
B
C
```

and in another table, we have customer name, date of order, order number
Example:

```
Jack, A, May 22
Jack, A, May 23
Ryan, A, May 23
Emily, B May 24
Jack, A May 25
Emily, B, May 25
Ryan B, May 26
Hannah, C, May 28
Jack, C, May 28
Emily C, May 29
Hannah C, May 30
```

I want to know which customer have the highest count for each menu item, and what is that count

Example of output

```
Order .... Customer....Count
A Jack  3
B  Emily 2
C Hannah 2
```

What is the proper sql query statement (oracle) to get such a result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation and window functions:

```
select co.*
from (select customer, ord, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by ord order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by customer, ord
     ) co
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: PARTITION BY is missing

Comment: @GordonLinoff  thanks it works, but is there a way where I do not print out the seqnum, I don't want to show it.

Comment: Simply list the columns instead of `select *`